# Ubuntu keeps going to log-in screen on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, login-screen, oracle, virtualization

I installed Ubuntu on an Oracle VM VirtualBox and when I log in, it seems to load, but then goes back to the login screen again. The same problem happens when I "try" or "install," except "try" brings me to a desktop for 0.5 seconds, then returns to a log-in screen.

**Computer information:**

Clean install Windows 10 64-bit, all automatic updates

Intel Pentium CPU Dual Core G4400 # 3.30 GHz, Intel Core (Socket 1151) ,  (2 x 3.3GHz CPU - 3MB Cache +Iris Pro 510 Graphics)

8 GB RAM

Motherboard: Asus H170 Pro
AMD Radeon HD 6800 series
Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.0.12 r 104815

**VM:**

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 32-bit from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Base Memory: 2048Mb

Acceleration PAE/NX, KVM Paravirtualizaiton

Video Memory 12 Mb

SATA Port 0: 8Gb, VDI, dynamic allocated

**Errors while loading:**

ACPI PCC Probe failed...
43.88350 piix4_smbus 0000:00:07:0 SMbus...

Thank you!

Comment: When you see the small logo with a purple background when booting Ubuntu press any key. You should see a menu with some options such as "Try Ubuntu", "Install Ubuntu", "Memtest" and "Boot from hard drive". Press F6 and select `nomodeset`. Esc to exit the popup menu, then select "Try Ubuntu". Please see if that works.

Comment: Check the BIOS if the Virtualization option (VT) is enabled.
Let me know also if you installed VirtualBox 5.0.12 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling EFI under Settings => Enable EFI. It worked for me.

[image: Check the image here]

Comment: I installed Mint with EFI enabled and was also having to keep signing in, but when I turned of EFI, it would no longer boot. I turned EFI back on and it booted up fine. The constant logging in is a drag. Looks like I will have to re install without the EFI and hopefully that will do it.
Thanks for the direction!